# Reloading an Image with delay using javascript

Tags: image, webcam, reload, onload

I am failing for 2 days on trying to reload an Image using Java script.
I hope you can help!
the Image is displayed but doesnt Change after the defined 7 secunds...

it's not a server-side Problem while i can see in wireshark that the data isn't even requested by the browser...
is anyone having an idea where my Problem might be?
please see my code below for reference

```
<html> 
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="de-DE">
<head>
<bodyonload="DispayImage()">
<img src="/img/dynamic_live_1.jpg" width="600" height="450" name=Cam> 
<script language="JavaScript> 
var imageUrl = document.Cam.src; 
var random = new Date().getTime(); 
var delay = 7000;  
var counter = 0; 
var buffer = new Image; 

function DisplayImage() 
{ 
    document.Cam.src = buffer.src;
    LoadNextImage(); 
} 

function LoadBuffer () 
{ 
    var trickname = imageUrl; 
    ++counter; 
    trickname += "?counter=" + (random + counter); 
    buffer.src = trickname; 
    buffer.onload = DisplayImage; 
} 

function LoadNextImage() 
{ 
    setTimeout("LoadBuffer()", delay); 
} 
LoadNextImage(); 
</script> 
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

On first sight, your "setTimeout"-call seems to be wrong:

Try

```
function LoadNextImage()
{
    setTimeout(function() {LoadBuffer()}, delay);
}
```

Also, your body.onload has a wrong call, it says "DispayImage" and not "DisplayImage", but that might be a copy-paste error on your end.

Edit: Just tested the corrected code myself, and here it works (used some local images). One last error I found was that you don't close the "language"-tag:

```
<script language="JavaScript>
```

should be

```
<script language="Javascript">
```

Or, even better, the "language"-tag is not needed, all browsers use javascript as default when you use "script":

```
<script>/*Some code here*/</script>
```